# Optimal chart library for my site

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want a chart api that can work almost like google stock market chart.

That means a chart where it will go from one date to another and on it will be approximated points of some events.

Example of use:
I have a day of watching a video, each time I see something interesting I click a button. The clicks are not in interval times, but I still want to see a graph where I would see the clicks in each second but approximated (will be watching the whole day on a graph and that means a separate second won't be seen). Now if I take enough people who will click the button I will have good approximated values in some points and will see what points are interesting and what points are not.

EDIT:
My problem currently is that I have all the points where users clicked on the button, but adding them all in a chart would yield lies. For example 1 user clicked at 12:00 and one at 13:00, I will see that in the mean time suppose at 12:25 I will see that 1 person clicked. A bad solution for this is to insert more data putting 0's at every other place other than the data points. That will give me very ugly graphs as the points are in seconds and the graph should show 86400 seconds (1 day) at only around 1000 pixels wide. So I want a graph that can approximate the points I give him and put 0's at all the other points by himself.

EDIT2:
That means that most of the points will be clustered while just small portion not, and I want to show those cluster as interesting points and the non-clusters as just noise.

Comment: why not try wijmo for example? check out http://wijmo.com/demo/v2/#linechart|overview

Comment: If you're ok using third party service, why not just use google chart api?  You just include a JS library, set up your data and make a function call - presto - chart is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best Javascript charts library I ever seen is **[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)**. It's free (for non-commercial usage), can be used as it is, or with other JS frameworks (jQuery, Mootools, Prototype).

It generates points interpolation (i.e. approximation lines between irregular points, as you said) very easily. You can see that feature in the **[Time data with irregular intervals](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time)** demo.

Comment: Thanks, that is a lot better that what I have. But see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

+1 for google charts.  Your asking for something specific which require's work on your part. Google chart event's should help you in your quest [interactive charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/events.html)